# Oracle Apex ...Page Authorization in first log

Tags: authentication, authorization, oracle-apex-5.1

I have an application where users of my organization, who are not users of this application can register themselves in the first log. When they register, they can choose one or more app's profiles, like contract manager, supervisor etc. These profiles have specific authorization schemes per page, buttons, regions in app. The user must logoff and login again at the inicial log to see these menu's references 
Do you know of any way that these menu's references could be viewed/activated in the first of all logs?

The oracle apex version is 5.1.4.

Regards.

Comment: No idea. Just being curious: do you really allow people - who *register* to your application - to choose whether they want to be supervisors? If I were one of your users, I'd pick ALL profiles and do *stuff* to your data :) (yes, I'm being mean now).

Comment: These people are from organizational staff. These profiles are intended to internal app's proposals and are audicted and administered.

Comment: Sorry, I did not quite understand. Do you need registered users to be redirected to the login page? If so, why do not you simply redirect the user to the login page? there is a specific component in apex to do this ...

Comment: Romeu,  These are users who are already registered in the organization's Active Directory, but they are not users of that particular system. If they are not they will be redirected to another page, where they can register in specific profiles....

Comment: At the end of this self registration they are directed to the home ...page and still do not see links in the menu that should have already seen. They should log off and log back in to this. I'm looking for a solution, in which they do not have to log off.

Comment: @Littlefoot read the comments above, please.

Comment: @romeuBraga read the comments above, please.

Comment: See if you can utilize `APEX_CUSTOM_AUTH.set_user (p_user => :PX_APEX_USERNAME);` (where PX_APEX_USERNAME is an item that contains username of that person).

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question as follows:

1. I do a self-criticism for the question because I consider it to have failed to take into account all aspects of information security. Even though I'm always careful about security, a solution of this kind might attend me, considering a IT's well secure work's scenario, but may not be the case for all environments.
2. I would consider this a valid question for security experts, who could see in the scenario that I proposed, a failure in the APEX environment, in which I have not yet seen.